# Is this sentence grammatically correct: "She would make for a convincing Amy."

Tags: tenses, past-tense, would, mood

This sentence is part of dialogue between producer and actor, when she was convincing them to cast her in film.

The film is ready now. During the premiere, they were recalling a previous moment that happened in past.

Comment: Yes, the sentence is grammatical.

Comment: However, it's *film*, not *flim*.

Comment: @Lawrence please explain why it is correct. i am new  in english

Comment: This question should have been posted on https://ell.stackexchange.com, if you are new to English.

Comment: Hi Raghav, welcome to EL&U. Regrettably, I'm flagging this question for closure: proofreading questions ("Is this correct?", "Is there a better way to write this passage?") are off-topic unless a specific source of concern in the text is clearly identified. For further guidance, see [ask] and take the EL&U **[Tour]**. :-)

Comment: Dropping the *for* would sound a lot more natural (especially because it's talking about a person), but I don't think leaving it is technically wrong.

Comment: @Chappo next time i will be more about the question template which we follow here. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

This is correct, though unusual, which makes it powerful. You are using "Amy" (the character) as a kind of non-personal object, "[objectification](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/45944/what-is-the-opposite-of-personification)" being the opposite of personification, which expands and expounds on what type of character "Amy" is.

"Objectifying" a person, if not done too often, paints a wider view of the person being described. English celebrates figurative usage, just like this.

It works because the rest of the sentence structure is correct. Here are some other correct examples of the same structure you are using (outside of the objectification):

> That would make for a convincing *argument*.

or

> It would have made for an impactful *movie*.

Or in politics...

> This will make for an effective *presidential term*.

The advantage is that you are being both descriptive and brief at the same time. It is unusual, but correct; and that is its value. Sentences like this spice up English usage, making it more memorable and quotable.

As per the story you ask about using it in, I say go for it!

Answer (score -1):

This use of *to make for* is confusing. It is a usual idiom, but stems from an expression that is rare now. I suppose it stems either from *to make for* "to go to" (also in German "(nach [place]) machen") or from a sense *to prepare for, to bring* (in my humble opinion).

Either way or another, it now also means *to tend to produce or result*, which is what it means here (see https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/make_for. So yes, it is correct. In effect *would make for* means *to resemble*. But *will make for* rather means *to contribute to*, as far as *an Amy* is a symbol rather than a status.