# What literary device is used in this phrase? (Opposite of personification?)

Tags: single-word-requests, literary-device

Writing an analysis on a short story.
This line is talking about one of the main characters who plays music throughout the house often.
...it is not "like living with a person at all, it was like living with a sound."

My question is what word/literary device could I use to describe the comparison of this person to a "sound." Objectification? Dehumanization?
Thanks.

Comment: Looks like a simile to me.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the opposite of "personification"?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/45944/what-is-the-opposite-of-personification)